# Google mini xml returns 504 error code

Tags: xml, google-search-appliance

We have a Google mini indexing a client site returning results in XML format. Occasionally (1 in 1000 requests in my small sample) results XML is not returned but the following is instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE GSP SYSTEM "google.dtd">
<GSP VER="3.2">
    <ERROR>504</ERROR>
</GSP>
```

I can't find any information on what this error means or how to resolve it. Has anyone seen it before or have any ideas to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 504 is an internal timeout.  From [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/52/troubleshooting/Designing_Search_Solution.html#Queueing):

> The search appliance can also return a 500 or 504 error response if a processing thread is unable to respond with results within a time period. The internal timeout period on the search appliance before a 500/504 error is thrown can vary depending on the state of the response.

The next paragraph in the docs suggests that you limit the requests you send to the search appliance, to avoid getting a 504 error.

Comment: Thanks for this Mark, I have a related query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505062/google-mini-timeouts do you think this could be a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Tom,

I had a client with this error, and we fixed it by resetting the mini's index.

See [my blog post](http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/000561) for more information.

Dan